# EOF error in Python 3

Tags: python

```
def cell(s):
  a=len(s)
  for i in range(len(s)):
    if i==0:
        if s[i+1]==0:
            s[i]=1
        else:
            s[i]=0
    elif i==a-1:
        if s[a-2]==0:
            s[i-1]=1
        else:
            s[a-1]=0
    else:
        if s[i-1]==s[i+1]:
            s[i]=1
        else:
            s[i]=0

l=[list(map(int,input().split()))]
n=int(input())


for i in range(n):
  cell(l)
print(l)
```

> I am sharing the link of geeksforgeeks ide where i have written the code
> https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/
>
> In the above code constantly getting EOFerror
>
> l=[list(map(int,input().split()))]
>
> EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Is this python 2? Also, could you please try a bit harder to explain what the problem is? Because I can't reproduce that.

Comment: How do you run this program?

Comment: It is in python 3. I want to take list input . an the compiler is showing the error in the input() line. I have also used list comprehension but it is also showing the same error

Comment: @vikash: How do you run this program?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, you should provide an input in the web pages input field:

```
1 2 4
3
```

Answer (score -1):

The End of File error you are getting is due to Python 2's behaviour around the `input` method. It means that you need to give it a value before hitting enter. I gave it the following values `"1 2"` enter then `0` and received the answer `[[1, 2]]` is this what you would expect? You may want to try using `raw_input` or `input` in Python 3.

Comment: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/           See this link . I am expecting a input list

Comment: The OP is getting EOF-Error not SyntaxError.

Comment: I have tested it in the ide you link to and giving it the arguments on separate lines `"1 2"` and `0` (Python) or `1 2` and `0` (Python 3) both give the following result `[[1, 2]]`. If you don't give it any input in the "Input Goes Here..." box then I get the EOF Error as you do.

Comment: @Daniel I didn't mention any SyntaxError.

Comment: But that is the error you get, if you hit enter in Python 2 `input`.

Comment: @Daniel on my local Python 2.7.14 install I do indeed get `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` however on the website the OP is using I get `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` just as reported.

Comment: In my jupyter notebook(Python 3) I am not getting any error and it is functioning well but on online compiler like Geeksfoegeeks or even when I was giving online challenge it was throwing error